# Handling SPELL data with exact dates (feature request?)

Tags: r, traminer

I'm learning TraMineR and have used different types of longitudinal data. My original data is SPELL data with id, start time, end time and status, where the start and end times are exact dates, so my subsequences have varying lengths

With seqformat() I can chop the data (automatically) into 1 year pieces and convert into STS format, eg. where first variable is the first date, second variable is the first date + 1 year and so on.

What I would like to do is adjust the conversion so that I could use half year or one month time periods.

Here I have converted the dates into years with decimals with decimal.date():

```
         id start    end         status
1         1 1965.138 1965.974    1
2         1 1968.714 1987.237    1
3         1 1985.667 2003.933    2
4         1 1988.499 1988.665    1
5         1 1996.652 1996.878    1
```

The sequence object that is created automatically has the data in one year subsequences:

```
$ y1960.16803278689
$ y1961.16803278689
$ y1962.16803278689
$ y1963.16803278689
```

So with data with dates I would like to have the option to use also shorter than 1 year subsequence lengths. I understand that with seqgranularity() the opposite is possible.

Alternatively I'm interested to know if there's some way in R outside TraMineR to handle the SPELL data to create certain length subsequences.

Comment: The quick workaround is to round the years to nearest half and multiplying by 2.

`(round(start/0.5)*0.5)*2`

Now y1990 is 3980 and y1990.5 is 3981.

Comment: A further workaround is to create year labels with seq(<start>, <end>, <length of sequence>), so variable names don't matter.

Comment: Problem with rounding is that on most short periods start and end times are both rounded to the same direction, ie. length becomes zero.